# Making column data a url link from random array generated html table

Tags: php, html

I have random id generator that can have anywhere from 1 to 6 categories with multiple entries - see example

```
$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | c07-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea2b1| e8085-ded7-43ab-85127fe23f90bc|" ;

$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | MULTITENANT | c0407-8b93-49e4-991b-8213ea1b1| y | e808c5-ded7-43ab-858d-127f90bc| y|" ;

$ranGen = "IDENTIFIER | MULTITENANT | REGISTERID | c0347-8b93-49e4-991b-8213921b1| y | 1700011| e87fc5-ded7-43ab-858d-1273f90bc| y | 1700012|" ;
```

I have created a html table using array and explode to get table rows and table data.

Here is my snipit of that table code

```
<?php
  echo '<table>';
  $lines = explode("\n", $ranGen);
  foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $pieces = explode("|", $line);
   if(trim($line) !=="") {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";
   foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
   echo '<td>' . trim($piece) . '</td>' . "\n";
   }
   }
   echo '</tr>' . "\n";
 }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

What I would like to accomplish is making the column "REGISTERID" all the data as a hyperlink (a href="url">Register ID 1700011) inside the table?  Can this be done when I never know if I will even get back the register id as a column?

Comment: does the returned data include the column names in the first line? If so then you can detect this column and add hyperlink markup around the contents. If you don't get the column headings back then you're probably stuck, unless the data in that column is always in a very specific, detectable format, which can't be confused with any of the other columns.

Comment: yes the return data always includes the column names in the first line.

Comment: ok so when you process the first row, check for the column name, keep a note of what column index it appears at (if any), and then when you are processing the rest of the rows, when you reach that index (in the `foreach ($pieces as $piece)` loop), wrap the `$piece` text in a suitable hyperlink.

Comment: Do you mind showing an example - I'm not clear how to get the column index and keep for the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it - you need to identify whether the REGISTERID column is present based on the column names in the first row, and then on the subsequent rows, when you reach that index, wrap the item in a suitable hyperlink.

This is not tested but hopefully if it doesn't work precisely, at least you get the general idea. I've also modified it a bit so that it generates better table HTML.

```
<?php
  $strHTML = '<table>';
  $rows = explode("\n", $ranGen);
  $regColIndex = null; //this will hold the index of the registerID column, if any

  //loop through the rows
  for ($rowCount = 0; $rowCount < count($rows); $rowCount++)
  {
     if (trim($rows[$rowCount]) != "")
     {
       $columns = explode("|", $rows[$rowCount]);

       if ($rowCount == 0) $strHTML .= "<thead>";
       if ($rowCount == 1) $strHTML .= "</thead><tbody>";
       $strHTML = "<tr>";

       //loop through the columns
       for ($colCount = 0; $colCount < count($columns); $colCount++)
       {
         $isRegCol = false; //this will hold whether current column is the REGISTERID column
         if ($rowCount == 0)
         {
            //first row contains headings, try and detect the REGISTERID column
            if (trim($columns[$colCount]) == "REGISTERID") $regColIndex = $rowCount;
            $strHTML .= "<th>";
         }
         else
         {
           //all other rows contain data, check if it's the REGISTERID column
           if ($colCount == $regColIndex) $isRegCol = true;
           $strHTML .= "<td>";
         }

         //now display the content
         if ($isRegCol == true) $strHTML .= "<a href='http://www.example.com'>".trim($line[$lineCount])."</a>";
         else $strHTML .= trim($line[$lineCount]);

         if ($rowCount == 0) $strHTML .= "</th>";
         else $strHTML .= "</td>";
       }

       $strHTML .= "</tr>";
     }
  }

  $strHTML .= "</tbody></table>";
  echo $strHTML;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I will add this over the weekend to test it out.